# Set multiple objects to the same z value using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, objects, transforms

I have three objects, all with different z values. The goal is to rescale these objects so that the z values are identical for each object:

[image]

I'm trying to scale multiple objects relative to a single reference object, so that the z dimension for every input object is identical to the source object.

Here is my geometry node set up so far:

[image]

With this set up, I'm able to carry the z dimension from a target object and match the z value of the source object. For example, I can resize the cube so that it matches the z of the cylinder, if the node is on the cube and I select the cylinder as a target:

[image]

I want all three objects to be resized in the same way, but the thing that's limiting me is that I'm only able to resize the source object, since only the source geometry can be changed in the group outputs. Any ideas on how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Would a new geometry including the three rescaled objects be acceptable ? Because as you wrote, the GN modifier can not modify other objects that the one it as added to.

Comment: Yes a new geometry would work as well. I'm thinking this is where instancing would come in handy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

The following *GeometryNode* modifier is added to a *Single Vertex*.

[image: GN Graph]

**1.** The *Add Object* node group is adding a new point to a point cloud by transferring the *Location* of the input object to its *Position* and by setting its *Radius* to the height ratio between the reference object and the input object.
**2.** In the main GN graph, each target object position and height ratio are transferred to a point, collected in a point cloud.
**3.** Target geometries are also collected as instances through the *Geometry to Instance* node.
**4.** The point cloud is used to instance the associated target objects, taking advantage of the *Radius* attribute to scale these.

Resources: [image]

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you.